# Hough circles bug (Python, Open CV)

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

This piece of code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('circles.jpg',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                            param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
```

raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arnaud\Desktop\Cercles\circles.py", line 8, in <module>
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HOUGH_GRADIENT'
```

Do you know why please?

Comment: cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT doesn't work.

Comment: Does [this code](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html) work for you? What OpenCV version are you using?

Comment: No, this code doesn't work. I am using OpenCV 2.4.9 and Python 2.7.

Comment: Hum. Your answer is the same code as my question. And it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please pay close attention. It's different. Worst case scenario, copy/paste what I wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT` instead.

Comment: He is actually using `cv2.cv.` not just `cv.`